# Openshift 3.11 How to setup permenant token for pulling from integrated docker registry

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm using openshift 3.11 and I have a very hard time figuring out how to setup permenant token for image pull and push.
After I do docker login it is ok, but eventually that token expires.
By the documentation it seems that services account :  default ,builder should have access.

As you can see each of them have some default dockercfg:
Labels:              
Annotations:         
Image pull secrets:  default-dockercfg-ttjml
Mountable secrets:   default-token-q4x4w
                     default-dockercfg-ttjml
Tokens:              default-token-729xq
                     default-token-q4x4w
Events:

default-dockercfg-ttjml, Which has really weird username and password. Read the documentation many times and still I can't understand how to setup a permanent token. Can someone explain me in a plain manner what is the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `serviceAccount` token does not expire until create it again. Look [0] for details. If you want to create `docker` authentication `secret` against external docker registry, refer [1] for details.

[0][Managing Service Accounts](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/service_accounts.html#dev-managing-service-accounts)

```
The generated API token and registry credentials do not expire, but they can be revoked by deleting the secret.
```

[1][Allowing Pods to Reference Images from Other Secured Registries](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/managing_images.html#allowing-pods-to-reference-images-from-other-secured-registries)

```
$ oc create secret generic <pull_secret_name> \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Comment: Hello, the question is that I don't want to use for external but for the internal docker registry that is cluster wide

Comment: I don't want to access external registry. I need a token for the internal default registry of openshift. It seems that permenant token is needed for that as well.

Comment: The default serviceaccount (default, builder) do not expire, and their `serviceaccount` is built in and the authentication token is also created by internal process. You can verify as you delete above secret, it will create again automatically.